# Expressing adding up all the elements of a matrix/vector to get one scalar value mathematically?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to mathematically express adding up all the elements of a matrix that we do not know the dimension or it changes and is not fixed? I want to know how to write the summation in general?

Given $v$ as a vector with unknown dimension, $\sum v$ is incorrect.

Comment: You could denote $v=(v_1, v_2, v_3)$, then write the sum as
$\sum_{i=1}^{3} v_i$, I think that's the most standard way to do it. For a matrix you typically have two indeces (for row and column respectively), so you would need two sums.

Comment: If $\vec v = (v_1,v_2, \cdots, v_n)$ then you could just write $\sum_{i=1}^nv_i$.

Comment: @Snildt, how we can show the calculation in general. I mean if we do not know the dimension or the dimension is not fixed.

Comment: I might use $\sum_i v_i$ (if $v$ is a vector) or $\sum_{i,j} v_{ij}$ (if $v$ is a matrix), or else introduce your own notation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with the $(i,j)$th entry given by $A_{i,j}.$ Let ${\bf 1}_k$ denote a $k\times 1$ column vector of ones. Then the sum of all elements of $A$ can be written as

$${\bf 1}_m'A{\bf 1}_n=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m A_{i,j}$$

---

Note: Technically, the above uses the dimensions of $A$. How you would sum elements of $A$ without knowing its dimensions anyway?

Comment: the purpose is to show the operation in general. For example, assume we have a vector that we do not know the dimesion and just want to tell the reader that in this occasion, add the elements up.

Comment: Well in a programming context, I suppose one may simply apply a "sum" operation to an array.  If I'm writing a paper with matrices though, I would likely specify dimensions (this can be a generic "$m\times n$" for instance).